# A Google Iframe / Search box

Tags: feature-request

Can we add google in an iframe or perhaps a search form to the SO Question page as an alternative to actually procceding with asking your question. Maybe some people will chuck a hail mary into the box and see if they can find an answer there first? In a lot of cases i think people are worried about the wear and tear on their machines involved in actually visting google and looking for a solution. This could also alleviate some of the stress currently placed on the flag and close vote buttons that are becoming rather worn on SO. I mean who wants to replace those mechanics?

---

Perhaps we show a list of top 10 results similar to possible dups for the question title? It doesn't have to be google either although that seems to be the defacto search these days. I know theres a search API.

---

Perhaps this only occurs for users of lower rep (newbs).
Also this could only be displayed when an automatic filter of Low quality question is invoked.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of getting a box where you can ask a question, you get a google search box?

Comment: It says add.... not replace.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate questions list that appears?

Comment: Yes. Duplicated wouldn't show deleted questions along the same grounds. Maybe we just show a list of google results for the question title.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this he;ps?

Comment: Alot of posts closed as low quality questions, and alot of accepted answers containing nothing more than a link the person probably just googled. Also alot of comments recommending the end user just google for the solution.

Comment: If people aren't reading the suggested duplicates, I don't think they're going to read the search results either. People that ask extremely easy questions that even a few minutes of searching would solve tend to be extremely lazy, or conducting breaching experiments. I don't think this would deter either one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the need to... SO is here because the questions about to be asked might not be on google. see the before hand questions when you are about to ask a question. Smile for the cam :D

Comment: It actually is possible to embed a Google Search results page inside an iframe (using a proxy server). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966476/google-search-results-in-iframe-alternative