# Should the search function also use your keywords to search Google?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

It seems to me that a lot of the questions that get asked by newbs like myself can be answered easily by searching Google, but people appear not to think about searching Google before they search SO.

Would it be entirely inappropriate to suggest that included in the provided SO search functionality is a section that returns Google search results using the same keywords? Seems like it might save on a few duplicates.

I think what I'm suggesting is a partially revised version of a suggestion that has already been made [here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124855/a-google-iframe-search-box) In my mind, it wouldn't be that difficult to add two sections to the duplicate questions list, one for SO and one for random stuff that Google can come up with *meaning from external sites, not from SO*.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question. That question suggests using Google search functionality to search SO, I mean using Google to return potential answers on other sites.

Comment: I don't think we really want to send users away again from a search; that's what you use Google for *directly*.

Comment: And yet users don't use Google directly, they post duplicates on SO. There's some sort of feedback missing there, considering SO doesn't wish to cater to duplicates.

Comment: Searching sites other than SO is **not** going to help prevent duplicates. People that don't read and don't research are the problem here, additional tech is not going to prevent that and *certainly* not tech that'll search the wrong part of the internet.

Comment: For me Google often returns much better results than the built in search. I also find the the inbuilt duplicate detection is better than the search - I often use that.

Comment: That's a good point, however I still believe this suggestion could hold some merit. Often when I was subjected to the suggested duplicates list I would either find that my question became too specific whilst requiring a generic answer or that the area of questions suggested would sometimes be too broad. Using SO's keyword search functionality in Google could easily yield some results that I would definitely click on in Google had I known which keywords would be important. The issue is that new users may not fully understand how to find the right content with the right keywords.

Comment: I won't quote directly, but in the laws of usability, only a bad designer will ever blame the user for their mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Why would we want to show results from sites outside Stack Exchange? This is not what the network is about.

I can see one benefit however - showing results from other sites *within* the network. For example if I were to ask a more design type question on Stack Overflow it might already have been asked on Programmers. Showing results from Programmers (or Game Development or UX) would direct me to a more appropriate site and also prevent the asking of cross site duplicates.

Comment: The network is about information and solving problems. I don't see how this would conflict with that aim.

Comment: @RichardCane: The network is about making money by showing ads.  Why send users away to other sites?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom that's not what our network is about - ads only enable us to support our goals, they aren't our goals.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

The more content StackExchange has, it has more chance for referrals from Google. The duplicates are actually very important by containing words that real people use to describe a problem. The duplicates are a gateway to the actual q&a that contains the answer. Some moderators may not like having to repeatedly close duplicates, but they are vital to the health of the site as it relates to new visitors and search engine referrals.